# Why does Firefox execute Javascript incredibly faster than other browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, performance-testing

I'm performance testing the below Javascript code snippet under Firefox, Chrome, and Safari

```js
var f = function(x) {
 return Math.sin(x);
}

function testSpeed() {
 console.log("test started, please hold on...");
 var time = Date.now();
 for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
  for(var x = 1; x < 200000; x ++) {
   f(x);//replace by Math.sin(x) here
  }
 }
 console.log("total time = " + ((Date.now() - time) / 1000.0));
}

testSpeed();
```

The results are:

**0.12s under Firefox**, same when I replace the `f(x)` call by `Math.sin(x)`.

**5.2s under chrome**, same when I replace the `f(x)` call by `Math.sin(x)`.

**7.12s under Safari** but surprisingly only **0.56s** when I replace the `f(x)` call by `Math.sin(x)`.

This makes Firefox ~50x faster than Chrome and ~70x faster than Safari, is there any known reason for that?

Also under Safari why does the direct call to `Math.sin(x)` make a huge difference (~13x faster) compared to the `f(x)` call?

Comment: interesting. even edge is faster than chrome. score: 0.287

Comment: What's the speed when you delete the `f(x)` call entirely, or delete the body of `f`? Since it has no effect, the engine could reasonably eliminate it.

Comment: @Ryan without f(x) Firefox keeps the 0.12s execution time, Chrome surprisingly goes down to 0.18s and Safari to 0.54s, for some reason function calls affect performance dramatically under Chrome and Safari

Comment: Function calls affect performance in all browsers. What you’re seeing is Firefox recognizing that the function doesn’t have side-effects and that you’re not using its return value, so it’s not calling the function at all. Safari appears to also recognize that `Math.sin` is pure and perform the same optimization when you use it directly, but doesn’t extend that to `f` in this case. Chrome might recognize you’re trying to do a benchmark and avoid eliminating dead code in the benchmarking function or something, but that’s just a guess.

Comment: Brilliant analysis @Ryan double checked by reading the returned value from f(x) and logging it at the end and Firefox went up to 4.1s. will write an answer!

Comment: Just tested in Firefox 75 vs Chrome 81. Tested with `Math.sin(x)` instead of the function call. Strangely Chrome showed 0.186s and Firefox 41.253s. 
But if I change `Math.sin(x)` to `let a=12;let b=423;let c=a+b` Chrome does it in 0.179s, and Firefox in 0.258s. 
On the other hand, if I instead test reading from DOM (`document.getElementsByClassName('round')[0].click()`) Firefox performs 35% faster in this case. My CPU is Q6600 and I'm using Windows 7 64. I'm wondering if other people have similar results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by Ryan in the comments, Firefox was actually noticing the function not having any side effects and its return value not getting used thus safely omitting the call. Changing the code as below made Firefox execution grow up to **4.1s**

```js
var f = function(x) {
 return Math.sin(x);
}

function testSpeed() {
 console.log("test started, please hold on...");
 var time = Date.now();
 var y;
 for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
  for(var x = 1; x < 200000; x ++) {
   y = f(x);
  }
 }
 console.log("total time = " + ((Date.now() - time) / 1000.0) + "   " + y);
}

testSpeed();
```

Note that without logging `y` at the end of the nested loop, Firefox still noticed the unused return value and omitted the function call. Execution time sticks at 0.12s when `y` remains unused.

As for why Safari goes faster when calling `Math.sin(x)` I'll just quote Ryan's comment:

> Safari appears to also recognize that Math.sin is pure and perform the
>   same optimization when you use it directly, but doesn’t extend that to
>   f in this case.